# cannot read property push of 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets, scope, socket.io

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    var socket = io.connect();

    this.messages = [];

    this.sendMessage = function(){
        socket.emit('new message', this.input_message);
        this.input_message = '';
    }

    socket.on('new message', function(data){
        this.messages.push(data);
    });
});
```

I am getting the data emitted by the socket, but when I try to push that data into the `messages` array, it shows the error `cannot read the property push of undefined`. What wrong am I doing?

Comment: please provide fiddle or plunker

Comment: please tell me the data is object or not. print the data in console

Comment: @SrinivasAppQube, it not a object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not work because you are calling `this` in the socket scope (`this.messages.push(data)`), which is not the same as the controller scope. That is why `this.messages` is `undefined`, because it is declared in the controller function scope, but not in the socket callback function scope. In javascript, each function has it's own scope (except arrow functions).

#### Suggestion

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
   var ctrlContext = this;
   var socket = io.connect();

   //using the this keyword here means that
   //it's in the controller function scope.
   this.messages = [];

   this.sendMessage = function(){
      socket.emit('new message', this.input_message);
      this.input_message = '';
   }

   socket.on('new message', function(data){
      //inside the callback function we have a different
      //scope, which means that this.messages will be undefined.
      //but by referencing the controller function scope, you
      //are now able to use the messages property set the
      //outer (controller function) scope.
      ctrlContext.messages.push(data);

      //as you stated, you will also have to call $scope.$apply
      //or else the digest cycle will not be triggered.
   });
});
```

However, if you would like to use the `this` keyword inside you socket callback function you could do that by using the [function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method, which allows you set the context of the executing function.

#### Example

```
var person = {
   name: 'John Doe';
}

//Create function and bind to context person    
var changeName = function() {
   this.name = 'Peter Smith';
}.bind(person);

console.log(person); // {name: 'John Doe'}

changeName(person);

console.log(person); // {name: 'Peter Smith'}
```

For you solution it would be something like:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
   var socket = io.connect();

   this.messages = [];

   var callback = function(data){
      this.messages.push(data);
   }.bind(this);

   socket.on('new message', callback);
});
```

Comment: I got your explanation, but i don't think that this code will work. you just replaces 'this' with 'ctrlContext',

Comment: Yeah, I'm updating now of how you can use the `this` keywork

Comment: If we use **$scope.$apply()**  after **ctrlContext.messages.push(data)**, then it will work fine. Anyway thanks for ur help